# In Stein's Lemma, why must it require a function $g$ such that $\mathbb{E}[g(X)(X-\mu)]$ and $\mathbb{E}[g'(X)]$ both exists?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In Stein's Lemma on Wikipedia, for $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, it requires that $g$ is a function for which the two expectations $\mathbb{E}[g(X)(X-\mu)]$ and $\mathbb{E}[g'(X)]$ both exists. I don't understand why $g$ needs to follow this, and am confused by the explanation that

> the existence of the expectation of any random variable is equivalent
>   to the finiteness of the expectation of its absolute value

I am wondering why the two expectations are needed and how it relates the statement in yellow above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectation of a random variable $X$ is defined as
$$
\mathsf{E}X:=\mathsf{E}X^{+}-\mathsf{E}X^{-},
$$
where $X^{+}=X\vee 0$ and $X^{-}=-(X\wedge 0)$. If both $\mathsf{E}X^{+}=\infty$ and $\mathsf{E}X^{-}=\infty$, then the expectation of $X$ is undefined. In particular,
$$
\mathsf{E}|X|=\mathsf{E}X^{+}+\mathsf{E}X^{-}.
$$
So if $\mathsf{E}|X|<\infty$, then each term on the RHS of the last equation is also finite and, hence, $\mathsf{E}X$ exists and is finite.